# RVM install system wide Git dependency

Tags: ruby, linux, git, rvm, rhel5

When I run:

> bash < <( curl -L http://bit.ly/rvm-install-system-wide )

I get the following error:

> Please ensure git is installed and
>   available in PATH to continue.

Git is installed:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.3)
actionpack (3.0.3)
activemodel (3.0.3)
activerecord (3.0.3)
activeresource (3.0.3)
activesupport (3.0.3)
arel (2.0.6)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.7)
erubis (2.6.6)
git (1.2.5)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.12)
mime-types (1.16)
minitest (1.6.0)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.6)
rails (3.0.3)
railties (3.0.3)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (2.5.8)
RedCloth (4.2.3)
ruby-oci8 (2.0.4)
rvm (1.1.6)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.23)
```

Comment: what happens when you type, for example, `git` on the command line?  Or `which git`?

Comment: [root@essnixapps01 ~]# git
-bash: git: command not found
[root@essnixapps01 ~]# which git
/usr/bin/which: no git in (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)

Comment: so its a problem with the path? how does one fix that?

Comment: Does `locate git` return anything?  If not, you'll need to install the tool.  If it does, then you edit the path by running `PATH="/path/to/git:$PATH"`, or putting that line in the `.bashrc` in your home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously have a path problem as git is not in your path.

First, are you trying to install RVM as root or not? 
Second, make sure git, and not git gem is installed and add it to your path like this(as root)

```
$: export PATH=/path/to/git/directory:$PATH
```

After running this command make sure `which git` return `/path/to/git/directory/git`.

Finally, you can try and re install the system wide RVM.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine that the `git` rubygem isn't the same as the command-line `git` DVCS tool that the RVM installation wants.  Take a look at http://book.git-scm.com/2_installing_git.html, and install the git DVCS tool on your system.  You'll then notice that `which git` returns a valid result, and the RVM installer will probably work.

Comment: I was able to install the single user RVM package just not the system wide one.